# Move several events at the same time in iCal

Tags: calendar.app

in iCal from Mac OS X Leopard, is it possible to move in a month view, several events at the same time clicking them with the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a quite ineffective way I am using in lack of a more elegant solution.
holding the apple-key pressed you may mark successively more and more events by clicking on each single of them.

I am still searching for a way of grouped marking of ical-events as we know it from, e.g., files on the desktop.

does anybody know if this is already implemented in ical?
if not, I would strongly suggest this.